# ASP.NET jQuery reload element on submit (Ajax POST/GET)

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Using ASP.NET I'm trying to reload only a part of my webpage using jQuery instead of using "location.reload();". It's a single page application. As the user submits a form the user credits change and the new value should be updated without a full page reload. The value for credits is retrieved through an Ajax Get Call and should be updated after an Ajax Post Call. I tried using "$("#userCredits").load(?);" within the Ajax Post but can't get it right. Do I need to make a partial view to achieve this? Thanks for helping.

**HTML** _Layout.cshtml

```
<ul class="nav masthead-nav">
   <li id="userCredits">
      //Paragraph retrived from Ajax Get Call: "#reloadUserCredits".
   </li>

   <li>
     <p class="user">@User.Identity.GetUserName()</p>
   </li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
//Ajax POST user pack (buy pack)
    $("#postform").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = {
            applicationUserId: $("#userId").val().trim(),
            packId: $("input.activeImg").val().trim(),
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/buypack',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
            success: function () {
                document.getElementById("postform").reset();
                location.reload();
            },
            error: function () {
            }
        });
    });

// Ajax GET user credits (navbar userCredits)
    var $credits = $('#userCredits')

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/api/user',
        success: function (credits) {
            $.each(credits, function (i, user) {
                $credits.append('<p id="reloadUserCredits" class="credits">Credits: ' + user.credits + '</p>');
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand... You already are getting the user credits via Ajax on page load. So you only need to do it again after he bought some more.

Have the Ajax request to `/api/user` in a named function. Below, I called it `get_credits()`. Run it on page load AND on success of the Ajax request to `/api/buypack`.

```
//Ajax POST user pack (buy pack)
$("#postform").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = {
        applicationUserId: $("#userId").val().trim(),
        packId: $("input.activeImg").val().trim(),
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/buypack',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        success: function () {
            document.getElementById("postform").reset();
            //location.reload();
            
            // Refresh the credits displayed on the page
            get_credits();
        },
        error: function () {
        }
    });
});

// Ajax GET user credits (navbar userCredits)
var $credits = $('#userCredits')

function get_credits(){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/api/user',
    success: function (credits) {
      $.each(credits, function (i, user) {
        $credits.html('<p id="reloadUserCredits" class="credits">Credits: ' + user.credits + '</p>');
      });
    }
  });
}

// Run on page load
get_credits();
```

Comment: Thank you for helping out. It's close to a solution although it duplicates the credits paragraph. See picture in link: 

https://niklasmalm.se/img/duplicate.png

Comment: Found a solution and it seems to be working fine now.

// Refresh the credits displayed on the page
$("#reloadUserCredits").replaceWith(get_credits())

Comment: I see. The "duplication" is because of `.append` in the each loop in `getCredits`. You could try `.html` instead. It would be more efficient. But your solution using `replaceWith` is correct too, since it works ;)

Comment: Oh now I see! I didn't notice ".html" at first. Your solution is much better. Now I can move on, thanks for helping out! :)